# How can I root my ZTE Score?

Tags: rooting, zte-score

I'm new to Android, but I just heard about rooting; and I'm already interested.  Anyway, I've been looking around, but I can't find a way to root my ZTE Score. :-(

So my question is simple: Does anyone know of the best way to root a Score?

Answer (score 2):

This device can be rooted using the Zergrush exploit (which is the base exploit in the Gingerbreak app).

To root:

1. Make sure you have the [ZTE ADB](http://www.zteusa.com/support/mp/201202/P020120216436387234095.exe) drivers installed
2. Ensure [USB debugging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16250/what-is-usb-debugging-can-i-keep-it-on-forever) is enabled on your device
3. Download [this](http://www.mediafire.com/?2pyj6p3vanu6d7x) zip folder and extract the contents
4. With your ZTE connected to your computer in USB debugging mode, run the batch file - this will use the Zergrush exploit to gain temporary root, and will then push the su binaries, as well as setting suid to make permanent root work correctly

[Source](http://androidforums.com/score-all-things-root/513540-how-root-zte-score-using-zergrush.html)