# Where can I find Google Play services?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, google-play-services

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace and when I try to use my apps, it says "This app won't run without Google Play services, which are missing from your phone".
Where can I find those Google Play Services as they are not in my menu nor in any of my settings? I had them before but now I can't find them..!

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en_GB

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Services can be Disabled (Turned Off), and it is possible you did so. To find out if this is the case, and to re-enable, use Settings>Application Manager, and find the List of Apps either 'All', or sometimes it is split into 'Disabled' (Turned Off). The 'All' or 'Disabled' lists are to the far right panel of this tabbed interface - scroll far right. If not in a Disabled list, the disabled apps are at the bottom of the 'All' list. Find it alphabetically to re-enable (Turn On).

Answer (score 0):

Simply Google: Google Play services to install it. This has worked for me many a time and you can even update it via this method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/77169/96277) by [wbogacz](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/10913/wbogacz), if you cannot find Google Play Services yet you think that you've not uninstalled it, then follow this solution:

1. Enable [USB Debugging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67249/how-to-enter-usb-debugging-mode-in-cyanogenmod), install ADB drivers in your PC for your device, and make sure that your device is getting detected in the output of the command `adb devices`. (Consider [Minimal Installation of ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/96277).)

   Alternatively, you may install a terminal app like [Terminal Emulator for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) or [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en).
2. - Connect your phone into PC and run:

     ```
        adb shell
     ```

     The command will let you enter into ADB shell.
   - The following  `pm` command will find all enabled packages in your device and `grep` will output `gms` for [com.google.android.gms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en_GB) i.e. Google Play Services.

     ```
        pm list packages -e | grep gms
     ```
   - The following `pm` command will find all disabled packages in your device and `grep` will output `gms` for [com.google.android.gms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en_GB) i.e. Google Play Services.

     ```
        pm list packages -d | grep gms
     ```
   - Alternatively, you can run the last two commands in [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) app.
   - If your system has the Play Services installed, then the output of one of the last two command should be:

     ```
        package:com.google.android.gms
     ```
3. If the package is enabled, then you can find it easily in **Settings → Apps → All Apps → Google Play Services**. In your launcher the app name would be **Google Settings**.

   In case you cannot see it in any said location yet it is enabled, then type the command:

   ```
    am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.google.android.gms/.app.settings.GoogleSettingsActivity
   ```

   The command will launch the **Google Settings** UI.
4. If the app is disabled, then you can enable the app using the command:

   ```
    pm enable com.google.android.gms
   ```

   Repeat step 3. to launch this app.
5. If you do not see any output in Step 2., then possibly your device doesn't have Play Services installed. In this case, AFAIK you have to flash a [Gapps package](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110241/96277).