# Go back to previous custom rom - adb issue

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, adb, custom-roms

I decided to try a custom ROM from [here](https://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager/device/i9300/developer/exodusrom?manifest=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.clockworkmod.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fexodusrom%2Fmanifest&name=Exodus%20ROM&deviceName=Samsung%20Galaxy%20S3%20(GT-I9300)).

I downloaded Exodus ROM to my computer, and via ADB transmitted it to the `sdcard/0/` folder. I then rebooted and flashed this custom ROM. Everything went well but I don't like this version, partly because it seems old.

**The problem** is that I don't know how to go back to the previous ROM(Jellybean).

I made a backup of Jellybean to a folder of `clockwordmod`, but when I flashed the Exodus ROM the Jellybean ROM was not there.

So, what to do? I have it on my computer, but the problem is how to put it back to the phone. The problems are:

1. The ADB connection is not working via USB cable any longer.
2. I could download an ADB app from Play Store that uses Wi-fi, but the Play Store is missing in the phone.

**How could I possibly solve this issue?**

Very grateful for answers.

Edit: I succeeded to downloading it to my phone, that is the zipfile that holds the OS jellybean. But at the bootmenu where I select the zipfile it starts but soon fails (installation aborted).

```
finding update package
opening update package
installing update
installation aborted*

And then the droid is laying down with a read exlamation above.
```

The zipfiles contents look like this

[image]

Comment: *but when I flashed the Exodus ROM the Jellybean ROM was not there.* -- what do you mean by it? Doesn't it mean the Jellybean ROM backup in the `clockworkmod` folder wasn't there? // 1) What's the current status of your phone? Can it boot into any OS? 2) I assume yes because of **2.**. Why can you not use MTP to transfer Jellybean ROM backup files from PC to SD card?

Comment: @firelord - I trying this right now, to download (a custom jelly bean I found on internet) to the downloadfolder via a http-connection. Hopefully it works. The folder /clockworkmod/backup/ was empty. I knew it was there before.

Comment: But you also wrote *I have it on my computer* -- I assume this the backup of Jellybean that you copied into computer as well. Isn't this the case here, or I misunderstood it?

Comment: @Firelord - yes the previous rom (jellybean) - an image is in my computer, but I cannot access it. So I am gambling on installing a fresh jellybean right now, from internet. Then later go transfer the image to the phone.

Comment: Very strange - I succeeded downloading jellybean zip and flash it but when phone reboots it still loads Exodus OS - but in another shape. I cannot just get it?

Comment: Do you know any mirrors that holds jellybean? Thanks!!!

Comment: Actually, you can access it if you connect your PC and Android via wifi/hotspot/USB_tethering and run a web/ftp server on PC. In that way, you just need to use a file browser like ES File Explorer, or a browser to download the image from your PC into Android. I know Exodus probably won't be having any browser but an apk (genuine) of Firefox can be arranged for sideloading (enabling unknown sources). // Anyhow, it seems the backup file isn't valuable to you so I guess you would stick with downloading from internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [T]he Play Store is missing in the phone.

It is because Exodus doesn't come with Google Apps (aka *gapps*). You'll have to flash them explicitly. You may try these links to download Gapps:

- [AndroidFileHost](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=5648)
- [PA-Google Apps Plus(All ROM's)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/reborn-gapps-5-t3074660) at XDA

**Caution**: Always flash gapps package meant for your ROM only. E.g. Do not flash gapps for 5.1.1 over a 5.0.2 ROM, or the vice-versa. You'll end up with bootloops, device stuck at boot logo, and what not!

> The ADB connection is not working via USB cable any longer.

Since you've already mentioned that the backup of Jellybean ROM is on the PC as well, you may transfer it to your Android device without using ADB at all.

- Connect your phone via MTP into your PC and transfer the files; or,
- As I mentioned in the comments, you can host an FTP server on PC (see this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/85027/how-do-i-setup-an-ftp-server-on-windows-7) for *know-how*) and access it over wifi/hotspot/USB-tethering.

  Thereafter, you can use a browser like [Firefox](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.mozilla.firefox)(apk available) to access the backup files and can download into Android.

  Alternatively, you can host a server (locally; see this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/106323/96277) for *know-how*) on your Android and do the transfer from PC. But that would be too much to detail here (unless asked).

> I don't know how to go back to the previous ROM(Jellybean)[?]

Once you've transferred files from PC into Android (in the folder `clockworkmod`):

- Boot into Clockworkmod recovery;
- Find some backup/restore option and select the backup file you transferred. It's best to clear (before restoring the backup) **Data**, **System**, **Cache**, **Dalvik/ART cache** to avoid any issue.
- Reboot the device.

Done!

Comment: thanks for answer - wish I could upvote. I succeded in installing the zipfile to the phones downloadfolder but I cannot intall the OS - It sais: installation aborted very zoon after opening update package. I dont know why - is it because the files is in .tar format?

Comment: Instead of upvote you may [accept](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer. Anyhow, 1) can you mention the link from where you downloaded this ROM? 2) Does it show any info in the error other than "Installation aborted" in the recovery? 3) I seriously advise falling back to backup of Jellybean to avoid these unnecessary troubles. 4) You didn't mention the name of your device.

Comment: I updated my question - theres an image of the zipfile. The zipfile is the file I wanted in the first place, that is - from my computer. I transferred it from my local webserver to the phone. My device: Samsung galaxy S3  (GT - i9300).

Comment: @java The content in the image are the files that clockworkmod makes as backup. You cannot restore a backup (there is a way but this isn't that case) using **Install Zip** option in recovery. Just go to recovery -> Backup and restore (or similar) -> choose your backup and proceed. It will show something like verifying files (checksum) and then will restore. Don't forget to clear data,system,cache, etc as mentioned in the answer.