# how to reinstall google play back onto my mobile

Tags: applications

How can i get the play store to work on my samsung galaxy ace it has changed to market. I have tried to download  it from the web but still will not work

Comment: What "market" exactly? And how did it change (I mean automatically?) I assume you are rooted? What rom? What android os version?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are rooted, installed a custom ROM and/or have a custom recovery, you can re-install "Google Apps" by flashing a GAPPS zip file.

The following website has ZIP files that you can flash in your recovery for most (or all) Android versions. https://basketbuild.com/gapps

Comment: [For Reader only]: In case the link dies, you may see this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110233/go-back-to-previous-custom-rom-adb-issue/110241#110241) or search for "Gapps" on this site. (Goo.im is dead for now.)