# Virtual track pad to control mouse pointer in android

Tags: nexus-4, broken-screen, mouse

I have a nexus 4 phone, which has lost half of the screen's touch capability due to its digitizer capability. I would like to have "[TouchMousePointer Windows app](http://www.lovesummertrue.com/touchmousepointer/en-us)" like app in android and place it on the screen where touch works. And thus use the phone inspite of this "nexus 4 soft touch problem".

I see that mouse pointer is by default available in android. Apps are present to use mobile as remote mouse to PC. Fusing these two application should be possible.

Is there any app in market for this requirement. Is there any simple method to overcome this problem?

The "[virtual trackball app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.spyfly.virtualtrackball&hl=en)" that is currently available is too primitive.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! For the app part, you better check with our sister site [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185). If I understood your question correctly, you want to [remote-control your N4 from your PC](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid)? Or rather use a "working part" of the digitizer itself to display a "virtual trackpad"?

Comment: @Izzy, it is the second one. I want to use a "working part" of the digitizer itself to display a "virtual trackpad" and use this virtual trackpad to control mouse pointer of the phone itself, so that I can access the content on the broken side of the digitizer.

Comment: Ah, thanks – reading your question again it seems I got confused by the second paragraph #D I don't have an answer, but related: [Resize screen for Dead touch zone](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57267/16575) / [Resize screen to display only on working part of semi-functional touchscreen](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/115484/16575). Not the solutions you're asking for, but maybe alternatives if the "primary goal" can't be achieved.

Comment: I read that, but it cuts the display also. I have this problem for more than a  year. Now the dead touch zone is half of the screen !!!

Comment: Then maybe it's time for either a screen or a device replacement – and ready the half-dead for some "second use" (see our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info)).

Comment: Thanks for the wiki link. I find two usages interesting. One more reason for posting this question is that I felt that such an app should be already present, because for a big phone or tablet you can use your thumb to browse and do most of the work (just like BB trackball) without using both hands.

Comment: Good points. Might I recommend asking that app question over at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) (link points to the question guidelines; we're quite strict over there)? As for the wiki: many of our tags have such wiki pages attached, just check them out when in need :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to move the cursor to areas where the touch is not working, temporarily moving the screen to the area where touch is working looks like better alternative to this problem.

[Niwatori-one-hand-mode](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-niwatori-fly-apps-window-t3031680) app in xposed framework, gives options like that. Using this app along with other Launcher apps like [LMT](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150) (launch bar) app solves this problem for me.