# How to control the phone with on screen touchpad?

Tags: input-methods, mouse

In Windows 10 and above there is an option like in the below screenshot to control the current device using a virtual touchpad. I'm looking for something similar in Android. To be more precise I'm not looking for an App to control another device but to control the current device.

[image]

##### Use Case

I have Galaxy Tab S7 which has fairly a large screen almost comparable to an office laptop. I often use Evernote, but there is no option to resize images in its native Android App. On the other hand web version of Evernote has the option to resize images, and also the web version works perfectly fine in Chrome for Android. But the issue is that the image can be resized only using a mouse click event, even the official keyboard cover of the Tab sends only a touch event instead mouse click event.

Comment: I am confused by what you want to accomplish with having a visual touchpad on an Android phone, blocking parts of the screen, controlling that same Android phone. Please [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/249242/edit) your post with a use case as to how the user would interact/achieve certain tasks.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Virtual track pad to control mouse pointer in Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131149/44325)

Comment: @MorrisonChang added a use case.