# Half of touchscreen is unresponsive. How can I make Android only use the top half (rotated by 90 degrees)

Tags: adb, touchscreen, broken-screen

So I have a broken LG G2 and a near-empty bank account, so buying a new phone isn't exactly an option right now.  The bottom 50% of the screen doesn't respond to touch.  Right now I am running BlissPop which allows 180 degree screen rotation, and that is currently my workaround.  But I'd like to use the top half of the display only.

I've tried using:

adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,960

but it breaks most apps (probably due to the weird resolution)

so what I'd like to do is use the top 50% of the screen, but rotated so that the 1080 pixel wide side is oriented up/down and have a shrunken phone in that top 50%.

This is what is going on right now:

[image]

And this is what I'd like to do:

[image]

Basically, what I'm asking is how to get Android to assume my screen is rotated 90 degrees and only spans the top half.  I'd prefer if the resolution was 4:3 so I could use more of my screen, but if 16:9 keeps better compatibility with apps, I will do that.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: From this:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/pvAKH.png, to this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lyWE4.png? is this what you're asking for?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize screen to display only on working part of semi-functional touchscreen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115484/resize-screen-to-display-only-on-working-part-of-semi-functional-touchscreen)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try out something like Assistant menu's cursor facility,

> Unfortunately, I am not sure where you could get one though.

It's you phone's hardware that is not working right? If so, you could just make all touch events in upper half with such a software and emulate that touch occurred in lower half somewhere? You would (most likely) need a rooted phone for installation of such a software though.

The one with Samsung's phones can be accessed from `settings/accessibility/dexterity and interaction/assistant menu` , I am not sure whether stock android has such a facility. You can then use the lower half screen by scrolling the cursor down, A bit cumbersome , it would be for sure though. You should search for such an app. Which (most likely) be a system app as it has to be available all the time.

Hope this proves to be helpful.

[image: Samsung's TouchPad/cursor facility]