# OnePlus One stuck in boot after resizing screen and DPI tweak

Tags: adb

My device: OnePlus One, CM 13.1.1, not rooted

Since the the strip above the on screen nav buttons is gone (no touch screen anymore) I was trying to resize the screen AND tweak the DPI accordingly as clearly explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115484/resize-screen-to-display-only-on-working-part-of-semi-functional-touchscreen) by Firelord. Unfortunately, instead of resetting to 500 DPI I've inserted 5000 DPI and obviously the OPO doesn't get past the "Cyanogen - Mod Ready" boot screen.

Error from the OSX terminal:

```
Libero-358:android Libero$ ./adb shell wm overscan reset
Error type 2
android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to window manager; is the system running?
    at com.android.commands.wm.Wm.onRun(Wm.java:81)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.wm.Wm.main(Wm.java:46)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:256)
```

Any suggestion to get my OPO back alive (beside whipping myself for being such a dumba*s...).

Comment: P.S. the device is still listed in the terminal (adb devices -l) even though soft bricked