# Display bound manipulation on an android device, to avoid faulty touchscreen area

Tags: adb, screen, oxygenos

I have a Oneplus 3T on which, the digitizer would not register a touch on the bottom 1cm of the display. I tried the `adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,100` command to set display margins, and it breaks a lot of apps (even after restart). The margin seems to scale differently to different apps. So, I used the `adb shell wm size 1080x1820` (original resolution: 1080x1920) command to set the height 100px less. Unfortunately, it shrunk to the middle, and there are 50px padding on the bottom as well as the top. But, all the apps are working well. Is there a way to shift ("translate") the display upwards on y-axis 50px, so that all the extra padding is on the bottom? If not, are there any other ways to achieve the same intention *(to shrink the display to the usable area)*? I can't find any comprehensive list of all the adb commands anywhere...

PS: I've tried activating on-screen navigation to offset the display, but on Oxygen OS 5.0.3, it also disabled the hardware buttons.

**Edit:**
The instructions I followed were from these questions [question 1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115484) & [question 2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57267). But it didn't help.

**Edit 2:**
Current device display configuration:

[image]

Here are a few screenshots to show what went wrong with the `adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,100` method. There is an empty space at the bottom of each of these app windows and they are different for each of them as well.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you correct the display density after using overscan command? I  once noticed that not correcting it caused some apps to crash.

Comment: The problem after the overscan method was odd. The actual margin of 100px is just about 6-7mm at the bottom of the screen. But in each of the app, the margin seems to be at different height from bottom. When I open Whatsapp, there was a 1cm blank white area at the bottom additional to the 100px overscan. But in the OOS settings, that white area was just 5mm. It seems to me that the margin is scaled differently to different apps. PS> I did always use custom font & dpi for the phone. Is there a particular criteria that I need to know calculating the dpi?

Comment: I don't have a criteria either. I used trial and error to find a DPI that could work with changes made with overcan, back when I posted that answer. BTW, you might want to look into logcat's output to get more info on why the apps are crashing.

Comment: The apps aren't crashing, just the *bottom bounds* of the *active region* of the apps are a little higher than expected.