# "Translate" Screen up using adb commands

Tags: adb, root-access, screen

The lower 30% of my samsung S10+ Screen is broken and constantly emits blinding white light, making it unusable at night and cutting down battery life drastically. I have tried to use adb commands to overscan the resolution 300 pixels upwards, but it tends to break most apps even after adjusting the density, and doesn't prevent the blinding light. If i change the image res it will shrink to the middle, but create black bars on the top and bottom. If I could do this, then translate the entire screen upwards to just have the black bar on the lower part of my screen that doesnt work, that would be perfect. Is there a command for this? This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203904/display-bound-manipulation-on-an-android-device-to-avoid-faulty-touchscreen-are), but it seems it ended as a dead end. Any help is appreciated.