# How to tell Android Auto not to use several rows of pixels at the bottom of the screen (physical frame/bezel is smaller than the screen behind it)

Tags: screen-resolution, android-auto

I got an after-market Android Auto infotainment. The issue is its physical frame covers several rows of pixels at the bottom of the screen.

Is there a way I can override the device screen dimensions in some config file somewhere so the system does not know about the 10-20 rows of pixels at the bottom? (So I don't have to cut the plastic bezel, which will surely turn out horrible.)

"Hey Android, I know you think the screen size is 2000x1000, but it is actually only 2000x990."

Comment: likely solution: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/android-resize-resolution-calibrate-screen-height-position.2728354/#post-83476275

Comment: duplicate of: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/115484/176353