# Android not detecting USB though it is connected

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, micromax-yu-yureka

I am using YU YUREKA that runs on Cyanogenmod 11.0 with Android 4.4.4. Suddenly I found that my device is not detecting the USB connection. Though my phone is getting charged, it shows 'USB not connected' in the tethering option. I have checked that with different computers and USB cables but without use.

Later I go to `Settings > Developers options > Android debugging` and enable the `Android Debug Bridge (adb)`. Then my device starts to detect the USB.

But when I turn off the Developers option, again it stops detecting the connection. If anyone could help me in this matter.

Also is it safe to use tethered data connection with `debugging mode` turned on?

Comment: For the last sentence, see [What is USB debugging? Can I keep it ON forever?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16250)

Comment: Try USBDeview for your pc. Install it on your pc and run it. In the list you have to find all the android related devices, mass storage, Right click on those devices and mass storage and Uninstall. When you cleared up all those devices and mass storage, Connect your phone to pc it will work.
-http://www.topnotchtablets.com/FixUSBproblems

Comment: Its definitely safe to use usb tethering with debugging on. There aren't many people using yureka with kitkat now to reproduce the issues. Consider updating to lolipop. Ohh and if you wanted to update to lolipop, please do `OTA UPDATE` and not `FASTBOOT FLASH`, since fastboot flashing will brick your device while upgrading bootloader from kitkat(32bit) to lolipop(64bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the last question first, yes it is save to tether with debugging mode on.

I'm not sure about the answer to the first question, because i'm not well known with cyanogenmod. If you were a normal android user i'd suggest looking if the MTP or PTP settings are set well. You can find these under `Settings > Storage > USB computer connection`

Hope this helps. I found this useful on my Nexus 4 using android 4 and android 5

Answer (score 0):

as a security feature, android requires that your phone be switched to a usb data transfer mode (which requires unlocking) before enabling the tether option. That way, a malevolent person cant just connect any usb device to your phone and drain your data.

The solution is to switch the usb interface from charging to something else, such as mtp

Comment: I keep using Select USB Configuration (on a lowly QS5509A clone phone) and switching to MTP or PTP, and I still can't get the "Connected devices" to show USB. It's gray and says "USB Not connected." (Meanwhile, the ONN tablets my client got me are working fine without complaints!)

Answer (score -1):

update your phone to lollipop.i myself use yureka and after updating it worked fine for me.